# video size comparison between html5 and flash

Tags: html, flash

I noticed in youtube, for the same resolution, like 360p
for the same video (with the same video id)
html5 videos are much larger in size than flash videos

is there any relationship on video size between html5 and flash?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean larger? file size?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what codec you are using and what are the settings of the video (bit-rate, frame-rate), codecs usually also have certain adjustments. Flash and HTML can both play .h645 video, same profile, same settings. In that case it would be identical (since it would be the same file), but not all browsers and operation systems support all codecs. For instance, this one is proprietary, and Firefox doesn't support it.

Theora Vorbis, the another codec, supported by Firefox, it, on average, offers somewhat more conservative compression, which offers perhaps a little bit better quality while sacrificing size. I.e. it is larger in size, but maybe a little bit more sharp / detailed, not really sure, I can't tell the difference from watching the video.

So, while files don't have to differ in size, for the sake of compatibility you would have to have at least 2 copies of your video encoded in different formats, if you want to use HTML video tag.

Comment: but I use firefox on the same machine, use the same resolution, for the same video, the bytes of the packets I capture for html5 is nealy twice the packet bytes for flash. what is the potential reason? thanks